# How to dependency inject in storyboard managed UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, dependency-injection, storyboard

Hi all I'm trying to test one of the ViewControllers of my project. This class has a dependency on another helper class like this:

```
private let dispatcher: Dispatcher = Dispatcher.sharedInstance
private var loginSync = LoginSync.sharedInstance
private var metadataSync = MetadataSync.sharedInstance
```

Those helper classes are used in UIViewController lifecycle like viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. In my test I'm instantiating the ViewController class using the UIStoryboard class like this:

```
func testSearchBarAddedIntoNavigationViewForiOS11OrMore() {
    // Given a YourFlow ViewController embedded in a navigation controller
    let mockLoginSync = MockLoginSync()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // Here is too early and view controller is not instantiated yet and I can't assign the mock.
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourFlow")
    // Here is too late and viewDidLoad has already been called so assigning the mock at this point is pointless.
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

    // Assertion code
}
```

So my problem is I need to be able to mock LoginSync class. Under a normal circumstance I would use regular dependency injection by passing those helpers as arguments in the class constructor. In that case I can't do that because I'm not managing the View Controller lifecycle. So as soon as I instantiate it the helpers have already been used.

My question is: "Is there a way to do dependency injection for View controllers whose lifecycle we can't control or at least a workaround to it?

Thank you.

EDIT: So viewDidLoad was called because I was using IBOutlets in didSet overriden methods, not because of instantiateViewController being called. So I can move that code away and do injection after instantiating the view controller correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View controllers in storyboard are always initialised using `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, so there's no way to set any properties at initialisation.

I've found the following to be a good workaround…

Rather than using

```
let loginSync: LoginSync
```

Declare as

```
private (set) var loginSync: LoginSync!
```

Declare

```
func configure(loginSync: LoginSync) {
    self.loginSync = loginSync
}
```

Then

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourFlow")
vc.configure(loginSync: MockLoginSync())
```

You can also use this in segues…

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination) {
    case let vc as MyViewController:
        vc.configure(loginSync: MockLoginSync())
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

It's not perfect, but making the property `private (set)` ensures it can't be modified from another class, and the implicit unwrapping (`!`) means you'll get a crash if it's not set.

Use `configure()` methods in every `UIView`/`UIViewController` - once you get used to this pattern it becomes second nature.

Comment: I can still spot the same issue in your approach as in mine: calling instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:) method automatically calls viewDidLoad(). Which is where the loginSync is called. So after that call it is too late. What I'm looking for is a way to instantiate a IB managed UIViewController without having its viewDidLoad called straight away

Comment: No, that's incorrect. `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` does _not_ force `viewDidLoad` too be called. If it _is_,  then you're doing something else that's forcing it to happen. Please add the source for the view controller where this is happening to your question (the _minimum_ that shows the problem)

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I have a breakpoint inside the viewDidLoad and it stops every time I run the test. Actually I'm overriding the didSet method of one IBOutlet. How does affect viewDidLoad being called or not?

Comment: Are you referencing the main view / another subview in your Outlet's `didSet`? In that case it will force the whole view to load. To demonstrate the problem, add a new view controller class with nothing other than `viewDidLoad` method and instantiate it from the storyboard - you'll see that `viewDidLoad` isn't called at that point.

Comment: Yes, you're right .I've commented out that code and viewDidLoad is not called yet. That makes things easier. Thank you very much!

Comment: Useful tip… if you need to override a property's `didSet` but don't want to force view loading, you can check the view controller's `isViewLoaded` property first

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap `UIVIewControllerCreation` like this:

```
class func createWith(injection: YourInjection) -> YourViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVCId") as? YourViewController
    vc.injected = injection
    return vc
}
```

And use it like:

```
let vc = YourViewController.createWith(<your injection>)
```

Here is an example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let vc = RedViewController.createWith(injection: "some")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}


class RedViewController: UIViewController {
    var injected: String = "" {
        didSet {
            print(#function)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        print(#function)
    }

    class func createWith(injection: String) -> RedViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Red") as! RedViewController
        vc.injected = injection
        return vc
    }
}
```

Storyboard setup:

[image]

Code running result prints:

```
injected
viewDidLoad()
```

As you can observe, injection happens before viewDidLoad()

Comment: That approach still has the same problem: "calling instantiateViewController() method triggers viewDidLoad, where I'm using the injected classes so it is already too late.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. Update my answer with code sample.

Comment: You're right. I was wrong as the other colleague already helped me to spot my error. Your answer also makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @fewlinesofcode I think your method `createWith` has to be static.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use segues to navigate to your view controller so you can inject the dependencies during `prepareForSegue` like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SomeSegueToYourFlow") {
        if let yourFlowVC = segue.destination as? YourFlowController {
            let mockLoginSync = MockLoginSync()
            yourFlowVC.loginSync = mockLoginSync
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you apply that approach inside a test?

Answer (score 0):

### iOS 13, Xcode 11 solution

You can utilise the [`instantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/3213989-instantiateviewcontroller) for what you want to achieve. Just name all the dependencies in your `init?` initialiser, and use the `instantiateViewController` method to initialise your ViewController. This has an advantage that you can keep your variables private:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private let networkManager: MyNetworkManager

    // Name your dependencies here
    init?(coder: NSCoder, networkManager: MyNetworkManager) {
        self.networkManager = networkManager
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NetworkManager is missing")
    }
    
    /// Returns an instance of the MyViewController with dependency injection
    static func createFromStoryBoardWith(
        networkManager: MyNetworkManager)
        -> MyViewController
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyViewControllerStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MyViewControllerStoryboardID", creator: { coder in
            MyViewController(coder: coder, networkManager: networkManager) // The magic happens here
        })
        return viewController
    }
}
```

Where the `NetworkManager` is a simple struct:

```
struct MyNetworkManager {
    var id: String
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
let networkManager = MyNetworkManager(id: "ABCDE")
let myViewController = MyViewController.createFromStoryBoardWith(networkManager: networkManager)
```